# ¿Cómo renderizar un icono de React Icons, de forma dinámica?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo `React`, y me encontré con un problema que no pude solucionar (de la forma que explico a continuación), resulta que al importar un icono de **[React Icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons)** la forma es

```
import {FaIconName} from 'X';
```

Pero quise hacerlo de forma dinámica, y creé un componente que me retorna lo que estoy buscando: un `<div>` con un título y un icono.

```
export function SidebarItem({ item }) {
 
 return (

   <div className='sidebar_item' key={item.title}>
     <Link to={item.path}>
       <div className='flex'>
         {item.title}
       </div>
     </Link>
   </div>
 );
```

Cuando quiero anexar el icono, lo quise hacer de la forma

```
<{item.icon}/> ----> con la sorpresa que no funciona...
```

Al darme cuenta del error intenté hacer otras formas como las siguientes

```
<{...item.icon}/>
{<{...item.icon}/>}
<`${item.icon}`/>
```

Aún todas sin funcionar.

Y aunque buscando aquí mismo encontré soluciones, como crear una función externa que evalúe el nombre del icono y retorne un componte de adecuado a la validación, lo que realmente quiero es salir de dudas si lo que estoy haciendo no se puede hacer, o simplemente no lo estoy aplicando de forma correcta, y con esto me refiero a hacer cosas justamente como estas:

```
<{...item.icon}/>
{<{...item.icon}/>}
<`${item.icon}`/>
```

Porque pensé que los literal strings me permitirían incluir los angle brackets `</>` pero al parecer no.

Gracias.

Comment: De qué forma estas enviando el componente del icono hacia tu componente Sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo tu ejemplo si el icono lo importas así:

```
import {FaIconName} from 'X';
```

Y lo puedes renderizar como un componente:

```
<div><FaIconName /></div>
```

Puedes guardarlo en `item` así:

```
item:{
  path:"path",
  title:"title",
  icon: <FaIconName />
}
```

Y renderizarlo como si fuera una prop mas:

```
export function SidebarItem({ item }) {
     return (
       <div className='sidebar_item' key={item.title}>
         <Link to={item.path}>
           <div className='flex'>
             {item.icon} {item.title}
           </div>
         </Link>
       </div>
     );
```

Comment: Tasio, que te parece mejorar la respuesta con un ejemplo práctico de tu solución... suena bien no? ;)

Comment: Exactamente lo que buscaba muchas gracias por tu colaboración.